# ServiceStack Swagger not matching custom route

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

I am using the ServiceStack Swagger Api.

I can generate the documentation if my routes have parameters after the resource ,ex: /items/{itemid}

if I have a route with {version}/items/{itemid}, I am not able to generate the swagger documentation. How do I generate the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The only route that can start with a path `{Variable}` is the [FallbackRoute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fallback-route).

Comment: What is the use of the resourceFilterPattern in the Swagger?

Comment: @Greens [Hide Services from being displayed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/e0540f79e11de0eae8de2867dfc90c1e6898547c/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerResourcesService.cs#L91) you can also use exclude Services from being displayed in Metadata by annotating Request DTO's with `[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]`